# Build is happening by default with g++ instead of arm compiler?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, arm

I am encountering a very strange issue. I am building my source for ARM with ARM compilers. I modified CXX field in makefile to build using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ instead of g++ but while building its still taking g++. Can someone please help me here? MY makefile has the following entry

```
CXX         = g++
```

I modified it to look as follows

```
CXX         = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

Shouldn't the build happen using  arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ instead of g++?

Comment: You'll need to provide your entire Makefile for a definitive answer.

Comment: Great question! I have a single line and we should deside what the invisible rest do! Wow! Can you please provide your Makefile(s) so that we can see what is going on? Thanks! If your recipe do not use CXX it would never work. And if you have a sub-Makefile, you must EXPORT your variables. And if... sorry, no, please provide your Makefile(s)!

Comment: I left CXX flag value as blank stiil its taking g++ as default compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to know why you're seeing what you're seeing without the rest of your build system, but here's some general advice:

Don't edit the makefile; pass the value you want on the command line:

```
make CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ <whatever your normal args are>
```

Command line values override those set inside the file, and usually get passed down to nested makefiles and override all the other confusing stuff that can complicate this.

If that doesn't work, check there isn't a `configure` script, or something else that you ought to be using instead.